# ODE solving in Scilab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have a certain ODE problem which needs to be solved using Scilab.

```
dx(1)/dt=k*x(1)-x(5)
dx(2)/dt=k2*x(2)-k1*x(1)
dx(3)/dt=k1*[x(2)-x(3)]
dx(4)/dt=k1*[x(3)-x(4)]
```

$x(5)$ takes value $0$ till $t_0$.

Can anyone help me with coding this problem? Any suggestions would be of immense help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need initial values of $x(1),\dots, x(4)$. Also, what happens to $x(5)$ after $t_0$ is unclear. Ignoring $x(5)$, we have a homogeneous linear system with coefficient matrix
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}k& 0& 0 &0\\ -k_1 &k_2& 0& 0\\ 0 &k_1 &-k_1& 0\\ 0& 0&  k_1 &-k_1\end{pmatrix}$$
The numerical values of the coefficients are also required. Below I picked some values for $k,k_1,k_2,t_0,x_0$, and for the time interval.

```
k=3
k1=1
k2=2
A=[k 0 0 0; -k1 k2 0 0; 0 k1 -k1 0; 0 0 k1 -k1]
function xdot=f(t, x)
    xdot=A*x
endfunction
x0=[1 2 3 4]';
t0=0;
t=0:0.1:2;
x = ode(x0,t0,t,f);
plot(t,x)
```

The output displays all four functions  $x(1),\dots, x(4)$:

[image: ode in scilab]

In general, the content of the function `xdot` should compute whatever the righthand side of $\dot{x}=\dots$ is. Piecewise defined functions can be handled with `if then end` operator.

Comment: What if I have a constant say ,theta alongwith the first equation instead of x(5),that is dx(1)/dt=k*x(1)-theta

Comment: @user2458552 You would change the function that computes the right hand side: it will be `xdot=A*x-[theta 0 0 0]'` instead of `xdot=A*x`.

Comment: ok thanks a lot!!If possible,can you check out this problem?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433744/function-using-if-else-in-scilab