# Function using if else in scilab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

```
function dx=m1(t,x)
dx(1)=(l0*x(1))/(1+(l0*x(1))
endfunction 
function dx=m2(t,x)
dx(1)=(l0*x(1))/[1+(l0*(x(1)+x(2))]
dx(2)=(k2*x(1)*x(1))-k1*x(2)
endfunction
t0=15;
function f(t,t0)
if (t < t0)
  {
   return m1(t)
   }
else
   {
   return m2(t)
  }
end
endfunction 
x=ode(x0,t0,t,f);
```

In the above code,I am defining two functions m1 and m2 and on the basis of a time point,say,t0,I am returning either of the functions.However,the error is showing **undefined variable:x**..Is it because I am using x(1) in both the functions? x is basically a vector containing x(1) in the first function m1,and [x(1);x(2)] in m2. P.S.- all the required value of the constants including the initial values are given.

Comment: `return m1(t)` should be `return m1(t,x)`, and similarly for m2. Some formulas are also missing closing parentheses. ... And at this point I don't think you have a *mathematical* question here (i.e., that the question is on-topic).

Comment: Other problems: `f(t,t0)` should be `f(t,x)`. No need to pass the global constant as a parameter, but $x$ is needed as a parameter. The function `m1` does not define `dx(2)`.

Comment: yes m1 doesnt have dx(2) at all.So,what should be done in such a case?

Comment: Well, you should know what the vector $dx$ is at every moment of time, i.e., both of its components. Otherwise you don't know what the ODE system is.

Comment: But for the system m1,x(2) is not in the vector..its just x(1)

Comment: the function is basically a discontinuous problem at time t0

Comment: If you have a system which changes from scalar to vector at time $t_0$, then it's not like any ODE system I ever saw. Looks more like two separate problems.

Comment: The rest of the values becomes 0 actually.x(2) is 0 in the first system.